# Pandas: exact indexing on timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on two pandas Timeseries object (the second coming from a group by on 30 minutes):

```
df_lookup = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10, 16),
                         index=('2017-12-15 17:58:00', '2017-12-15 17:59:00',
                                '2017-12-15 18:00',    '2017-12-15 18:01:00',
                                '2017-12-15 18:02:00', '2017-12-15 18:03:00',
                                )
                        )
df_lookup.index = pd.to_datetime(df_lookup.index)


avg_30min = pd.DataFrame([0.066627, 0.1234, 0.0432, 0.234],
                          index=("2017-12-15 18:00:00", "2017-12-15 18:30:00",
                                 "2017-12-15 19:00:00", "2017-12-15 19:30:00",
                                )
                        )
avg_30min.index = pd.to_datetime(avg_30min.index)
```

I need to iterate over the second, `avg_30min`, and lookup into the first, `df_lookup` in order to extract the value at index `idx`.

```
for idx, row in avg_30min.iterrows():
    value_in_lookup_df = df_lookup.loc[idx]
    # Here I'd use the object from the lookup to add a detail into a plot.
```

I tried using `loc` and `iloc`, the former returns:

```
KeyError: 'the label [2017-12-15 18:00:00] is not in the [index]'
```

while the latter:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2017-12-15 18:00:00] of <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

The expected result would be the row from `df_lookup` which index matches `idx`, somewhat similar to a dictionary lookup in plain python (`row_from_lookup = lookup_df[idx]`).

What's the right method to have an exact match on a pandas Timeseries?

Comment: Perhaps, `avg_30min.merge(df_lookup, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: Although it would be helpful to know what your expected output is.

Comment: added expected result, thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: I missed an essential part of the example code, barely the conversion of the index from string to datetime. And I found a more "pythonic" way to perform the lookup.

Comment: Care to explain why the downvotes?

Comment: Your question is ill defined. First of all, this example wouldn't raise a KeyError for `2017-12-15 18:00:00` but instead for `2017-12-15 18:30:00` as it is not in the index. It is not clear what you want to do when the value is not in the index either. No, you cannot solve this with `get_loc` because that will also raise the same KeyError for same value. You are adding additional constraints as the answers appear like "merge wouldn't work because df's are large" but those are also vague.

Comment: `df_lookup` is a dataframe containing a value for each minute, so no `KeyError` should occur, and using `get_loc` as showed in my answer it lets me really find the datetime I need. In case of a missing datetime the KeyError I can catch and manage the exception. I'm gonna update the answer adding some more values to `df_lookup`. Merging things is totally inefficient when dealing with GBs of size.

Comment: Using `.loc[dt_obj]` now works as expected. I think the problem was on the fact that I didn't convert the index to datetime in the example reported. Should I edit the question pointing that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `datetime.datetime` object such as:

```
dt_obj = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 15, 18, 0)
```

which can be extracted e.g. from another dataframe such as `avg_30min` in the example reported, a lookup into a dataframe which uses a `dtype='datetime64[ns]'` as  index can be performed using [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) on the `index` column:

```
>>> df_lookup.index.get_loc(dt_obj)
2
```

Then the position can be used to retrieve the requested row, with `df_lookup.iloc[]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a `merge` on the index columns.

```
avg_30min.merge(df_lookup, left_index=True, right_index=True)

                          0_x  0_y
2017-12-15 18:00:00  0.066627   12
```

Alternatively, find the intersection of indexes, and concatenate.

```
idx = avg_30min.index.intersection(df_lookup.index)
pd.concat([avg_30min.loc[idx], df_lookup.loc[idx]], 1, ignore_index=True)

                            0   1
2017-12-15 18:00:00  0.066627  12
```

Comment: Your first solution is not feasible, since the two dataframes are going to be GBs in size.
The second one is more promising , I'll test it out, even though it doesn't sound much pythonic.

Comment: @bebo Hah, pythonic is a myth. You can sacrifice beauty for performance, if you have to. And I can tell you the second method is exactly what the first does, maybe more efficiently.